# Parsing Multiple Date Formats using R function

Tags: r

I have data as below

```
  id      date_opened    total
1 A880C79F       2003-10-19   169305
2 BE8222DF October 05, 2018   107460
3 19F9E113       2008-07-29 15297152
4 A2FE52A3       2005-06-09 14897272
5 F6DC2C08       2012-03-31   124568
6 D2E55799       2007-06-20 13635752
```

EDIT: code was present along with error link:
This is the code I am using:

```
library(lubridate)
date_format <- function(df, col){
  formats <- c("%Y-%m-%d", "%B %d, %Y")
  df2 <- mutate(df,col = parse_date_time(col,orders=formats))
  return(df2)
}
```

date_format(accounts, date_opened)

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `col`.
x object 'date_opened' not found
i Input `col` is `parse_date_time(col, orders = formats)`.
```

I would like to convert the date format using a function definition as follows and getting
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC5Of.png)

How to rectify this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide the code of your function and not a picture. That will be easier for us to help you

Comment: Use `{{..}}` i.e `parse_date_time({{col}}, .....)`. Also It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Adding data/code as images is not helpful.

Comment: @RonakShah - when I use df2 <- mutate(df,col = parse_date_time({{col}},orders=formats)). New column "Col" is getting added. instead of overwriting the "date_opened"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curly-curly `{{}}` on both right hand side (RHS) and LHS.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

date_format <- function(df, col){
  formats <- c("%Y-%m-%d", "%B %d, %Y")
  df2 <- mutate(df, {{col}} := parse_date_time({{col}},orders=formats))
  return(df2)
}

accounts <- date_format(accounts, date_opened)

#          id date_opened    total
#1 1 A880C79F  2003-10-19   169305
#2 2 BE8222DF  2018-10-05   107460
#3 3 19F9E113  2008-07-29 15297152
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
date_format <- function(df, col) {
    col <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(col))
    formats <- c("%Y-%m-%d", "%B %d, %Y")
    df %>% 
        mutate(across(all_of(col), ~ parse_date_time(., orders = format)))
}
```

and call as

```
date_format(accounts, date_opened)
```